# It doesn't show me the data when I get the request through the postman, but with books it worked

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench, nodejs-server

```js
app.get('/usuarios',async function(req,res){
 var queryResult=await query(`select * from Usuarios`);
 console.log(queryResult);
 res.status(200).json(queryResult);

});
```

```
CREATE TABLE Libros
(
    id_libro         VARCHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
    cantidad         INTEGER            NOT NULL,
    titulo_libro     VARCHAR (250)      NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__Libros__END
    PRIMARY KEY (id_libro),
    CONSTRAINT CK__LIBROS__cantidad__END
    CHECK (cantidad>0)

);
CREATE TABLE Usuarios
(
    id              VARCHAR(10)         NOT NULL,
    nombre          VARCHAR(100)        not NULL,
    username        VARCHAR(100)        NOT NULL,
    pas             VARCHAR(100)        NOT NULL,
    rol             CHAR(1)             NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK__Usuarios__END
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT CK__Usuarios__END
    CHECK (rol='s' or rol='b' or rol='S' or rol='B')

);

CREATE table Prestamos
(
    id_prestamo          VARCHAR (10)        not null,
    id_socio             VARCHAR(10)        not NULL,
    id_libro             VARCHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
    fecha_vencimiento    BIGINT              not null,
    CONSTRAINT PK__Prestamos__END
    PRIMARY KEY (id_prestamo),
    CONSTRAINT FK__Prestamos__Libros__END
    FOREIGN KEY (id_libro) REFERENCES Libros(id_libro),
    CONSTRAINT FK__Prestamos__Usuarios__END
    FOREIGN KEY (id_socio) REFERENCES Usuarios(id)


);
```

This code works

```js
app.get('/libros',async function(req,res){
 var queryResult=await query(`select * from Libros`);
 console.log(queryResult);
 res.status(200).json(queryResult);

});
```

Comment: could you show your code with books, i assume there are data in usarios. What i would change are the backticks around the select.

Comment: app.get('/libros',async function(req,res){
 var queryResult=await query(`select * from Libros`);
 console.log(queryResult);
 res.status(200).json(queryResult);

});

Comment: Did you check your select statement in workbench, if it gives any results. you casn also edot your posts to add information

Answer (score 0):

This code work

```js
app.get('/libros',async function(req,res){
 var queryResult=await query(`select * from Libros`);
 console.log(queryResult);
 res.status(200).json(queryResult);

});
```